# Pytest how to check if the element is not enabled

Tags: python, pytest

I have some test scenarios where I am checking if the button is enabled.
First I verify if button is enable:

```
assert self.fisrstPage.btn_cancel().is_enabled()
```

do some actions

```
assert self.fisrstPage.btn_cancel().is_???
```

how to check if the button is not enable, there is no such method like `.is_not_enabled()`

Comment: There is some lack of context. Would be good to get a minimal viable code that is being tested plus the whole testing function.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the method `.is_enabled` returns a boolean put `not` in the assert statement: `assert not self.fisrstPage.btn_cancel().is_enabled()`

Comment: Getting an error when I use `assert not`: `FAILED test.py::TestPage::test_cancel_item - selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css ...` Maybe because the button disappears?

Comment: Without knowing what the rest of the class looks like, or what your program does it is pretty hard to tell. Unable to locate element: sounds like it can't find your button object